# Rspec / FactoryGirl: why do created_at and updated_at have same values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a test:

```
describe MyService::Thing do
  let(:foo) { FactoryGirl.create(:foo) }

  it 'tests something' do
    foo.update_attributes(...)
    p foo.created_at, foo.updated_at #these are the same
  end
end
```

Why are the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps the same and is there anything I can do to ensure they are different, other than manually setting the times?

Comment: Try `p foo.created_at == foo.updated_at`. Just because they render identically under `inspect` doesn't mean they are the same. (unless of course you'll get true above)

Comment: I get `true` for that comparison.

Comment: try to change `let()` to `let!()` and check again.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't make a difference - timestamps still match.

Comment: maybe `foo.reload` can update timestamps?

Comment: `foo.reload` before and/or after `.update_attributes` has no effect.

Comment: What if you add `sleep(1000)` and change `let` to `let!`? Do you actually update anything?

Comment: @BroiSatse no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are running is actually

```
FactoryGirl.create(:foo).update_attributes(...)
```

due to how `let` works. Now I can thing of a few possibilities why the timestamps could be identical, but you would have to debug into the FactoryGirl code (and beyond) to confirm.

1. FG.create does some clever stuff with its create that delays saving until its really necessary
2. Ditto but apply to ActiveRecord
3. Ditto but apply to database, perhaps it optimizes into a single transactional event.
4. Operations happen so fast that there is no difference at the resolution that timestamps are being recorded at.

To ensure they are different do

```
Fg.create(:foo)
sleep(1)
update_attributes
```

Alternatives to sleep could be a reload, using a time changer (timecop) ...